# Compare a table to itself in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a defect table that looks like this:

```
Ref# ID# Severity Status    Found_Date Verified_Date   Resolve_Date 
1001 21  2        Verified  6/19/2011  6/25/2011
1001 21  2        Verified  6/19/2010  9/18/2011
1001 21  3        Fixed     6/19/2010  10/12/2011      10/12/2011
```

In this system, the user can enter a record, which will have a `Verified_Date` (as in line 1).

Later the user can go back into the system and make a change and the system will genetate a new record, with the same `Ref#` and `ID#`, however, it will have a different `Verified_Date` (as in line 2).

To make it even more complicated, the user can go back into the system and change the `Severity` value, which will generate a third record and that record will have yet a different `Verified_Date`, but it will have the same `Ref#` and "`ID#`.

I was tasked with writing a query that will return the following result:

```
          Initial   Final                       Initial      Final
Ref# ID#  Severity  Severity  Status  Found_Dt  Verified_Dt  Verified_Dt  Resolve_Dt 
1001 21   2         3         Fixed   6/19/2011 9/18/2011    10/12/2011   10/12/2011
```

The record above is supposed to be the result of a query that will list all records where there was a `Severity` change and present it in the above format noting the `Initial_Verified_Dt`, the `Final_Verified_Dt`, the `Initial_Severity` and the `Final_Severity`.  I wrote a query to compare the table to itself and return all values where the `ID#` was the same, but the `severity` is different. The problem is that I get the following result:

```
          Initial   Final                        Initial      Final
Ref# ID#  Severity  Severity  Status  Found_Dt   Verified_Dt  Verified_Dt  Resolve_Dt 
1001 21   2         3         Fixed   6/19/2011  9/18/2011    10/12/2011   10/12/2011
1001 21   3         2         Fixed   6/19/2011  9/18/2011    10/12/2011   10/12/2011
1001 21   2         3         Fixed   6/19/2011  10/12/2011   9/18/2011    10/12/2011
1001 21   3         2         Fixed   6/19/2011  10/12/2011   9/18/2011    10/12/2011
```

I am getting every combination and I cannot figure out how to compare the table to itself and come up with the correct answer.  I hope that I explained it clearly enough and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In no way is this an elegant solution but it works:

```
select   REF#
        ,ID#
        ,INITIAL_SEVERITY
        ,FINAL_SEVERITY
        ,STATUS
        ,FOUND_DT
        ,INITIAL_VERIFIED_DT
        ,FINAL_VERIFIED_DT
        ,RESOLVE_DT
from     (select REF#
                ,ID#
                ,(select SEVERITY
                  from   DEFECT D2
                  where  D2.REF# = D.REF#
                         and D2.ID# = D.ID#
                         and VERIFIED_DATE = (select min(VERIFIED_DATE) from DEFECT))
                   as INITIAL_SEVERITY
                ,(select SEVERITY
                  from   DEFECT D2
                  where  D2.REF# = D.REF#
                         and D2.ID# = D.ID#
                         and VERIFIED_DATE = (select max(VERIFIED_DATE) from DEFECT))
                   as FINAL_SEVERITY
                ,(select STATUS
                  from   DEFECT D2
                  where  D2.REF# = D.REF#
                         and D2.ID# = D.ID#
                         and VERIFIED_DATE = (select max(VERIFIED_DATE) from DEFECT))
                   as STATUS
                ,min(FOUND_DATE) over (partition by REF#) as FOUND_DT
                ,(select min(VERIFIED_DATE)
                  from   DEFECT D2
                  where  D2.REF# = D.REF# and D2.ID# = D.ID# and D2.STATUS = 'Verified')
                   as INITIAL_VERIFIED_DT
                ,(select max(VERIFIED_DATE)
                  from   DEFECT D2
                  where  D2.REF# = D.REF# and D2.ID# = D.ID# and D2.STATUS = 'Verified')
                   as FINAL_VERIFIED_DT
                ,(select max(RESOLVE_DATE)
                  from   DEFECT D2
                  where  D2.REF# = D.REF# and D2.ID# = D.ID# and D2.STATUS = 'Fixed')
                   as RESOLVE_DT
          from   DEFECT D)
group by REF#
        ,ID#
        ,INITIAL_SEVERITY
        ,FINAL_SEVERITY
        ,STATUS
        ,FOUND_DT
        ,INITIAL_VERIFIED_DT
        ,FINAL_VERIFIED_DT
        ,RESOLVE_DT
```

If you're using pl/sql you can put all those little sub-selects into functions if you'd prefer. I did a wraparound select just to make the grouping easier.

Comment: Thank you so much John Doyle for taking the time out to answer my question; it took me a while to apply it to my entire table and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT ref#
                , id#
                , LAG( severity ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ref#, id# ORDER BY verified_date ) AS initial_severity
                , severity AS final_severity
                , status
                , found_date
                , LAG( verified_date ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ref#, id# ORDER BY verified_date ) AS initial_verified_date
                , verified_date AS final_verified_date
                , resolve_date
           FROM   defects
       )
WHERE  initial_severity <> final_severity
ORDER  BY ref#
        , id#
        , final_verified_date;
```

The `LAG()` function lets you inspect the previous row in the cursor/result set (I assumed that the verified_date column can be safely used to order the records chronologically); so you can easily check if there was a change since the previous record of the same defect. Similarly the `LEAD()` function lets you inspect the next row in the cursor.